# vagrant up failing when calling createhd with error VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS on new VM

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I use the Vagrantfile below as the basis for many new VMs (I copy it to a new directory) but today a new VM would not provision correctly when creating the disk with error VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS.  The disk file (source_code_disk.vdi in local vagrant 'tmp' directory) definitely did not exist at the start and is actually created during the vagrant startup but 'createhd' seems to think it already existed despite the FileExists check which meant it didn't exist when 'createhd' called.  Interestingly enough, if I "vagrant destroy" the new VM then the disk file is not deleted either.  In other installs based on the same Vagrantfile which work fine, the disk file is both created during "vagrant up" and deleted with "vagrant destroy".  Running "vagrant up --debug" did not yield any extra info and for brevity's sake I have not included the output here.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

file_to_disk = './tmp/source_code_disk.vdi'

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11"
    config.vm.hostname = "testdisk"
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    config.ssh.shell = "/bin/bash -l"

    config.vm.provision :shell do |shell|
        shell.inline = "sudo chsh -s /bin/bash vagrant"
    end

    # create a disk for the source code
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do | v |
        unless File.exist?(file_to_disk)
            v.customize ['createhd', '--filename', file_to_disk, '--size', 50 * 1024]
            v.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'SATAController', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', file_to_disk]
        end
    end    

end
```

Answer (score 6):

FIXED: by changing the relative path name to remove leading './'

```
file_to_disk = 'tmp/source_code_disk.vdi'
```

I removed the './' in the path to the disk file and a reliably failing install now completes with no issues - I suspect there is a path check failure combined with some timing issues when using relative paths prefixed with innocuous delimiters such './'

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

file_to_disk = 'tmp/source_code_disk.vdi'

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11"
    config.vm.hostname = "testdisk"
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    config.ssh.shell = "/bin/bash -l"

    config.vm.provision :shell do |shell|
        shell.inline = "sudo chsh -s /bin/bash vagrant"
    end

    # create a disk for the source code
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do | v |
        unless File.exist?(file_to_disk)
            v.customize ['createhd', '--filename', file_to_disk, '--size', 50 * 1024]
            v.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'SATAController', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', file_to_disk]
        end
    end    

end
```

NOTE: the original file works in most cases but every now and then when I copy the file to a new directory and attempt "vagrant up" I cannot get the VM to provision.  I know it sounds unlikely but it's true and here is the debug showing a failure that works if I 'vagrant destroy' and then remove just the './' from the file path - no other changes.

```
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "createhd", "--filename", "./tmp/source_code_disk.vdi", "--size", "51200"]
INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stderr: 0%...
DEBUG subprocess: stderr: 10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...
DEBUG subprocess: stderr: 
Progress state: NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG
DEBUG subprocess: stderr: VBoxManage: error: Failed to create medium
DEBUG subprocess: stderr: VBoxManage: error: Cannot register the hard disk '/home/stg38/vagrant/vstb/./tmp/source_code_disk.vdi' {0c2aa882-a1ef-427e-b7c4-85ef86c0f819} because a hard disk '/home/stg38/vagrant/vstb/./tmp/source_code_disk.vdi' with UUID {17da2b81-dd91-44a3-b60e-6c4921d8e75a} already exists
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057), component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreateMedium(HandlerArg*)" at line 449 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 1
INFO retryable: Retryable exception raised: #<Vagrant::Errors::VBoxManageError: There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["createhd", "--filename", "./tmp/source_code_disk.vdi", "--size", "51200"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create medium
VBoxManage: error: Cannot register the hard disk '/home/stg38/vagrant/vstb/./tmp/source_code_disk.vdi' {0c2aa882-a1ef-427e-b7c4-85ef86c0f819} because a hard disk '/home/stg38/vagrant/vstb/./tmp/source_code_disk.vdi' with UUID {17da2b81-dd91-44a3-b60e-6c4921d8e75a} already exists
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057), component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreateMedium(HandlerArg*)" at line 449 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
>
INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "createhd", "--filename", "./tmp/source_code_disk.vdi", "--size", "51200"]
INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...


Please fix this customization and try again.
A customization command failed:

["createhd", "--filename", "./tmp/source_code_disk.vdi", "--size", 51200]

The following error was experienced:

#<Vagrant::Errors::VBoxManageError: There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["createhd", "--filename", "./tmp/source_code_disk.vdi", "--size", "51200"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create medium
VBoxManage: error: Could not create the medium storage unit '/home/stg38/vagrant/vstb/./tmp/source_code_disk.vdi'.
VBoxManage: error: VDI: cannot create image '/home/stg38/vagrant/vstb/./tmp/source_code_disk.vdi' (VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreateMedium(HandlerArg*)" at line 449 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
>

Please fix this customization and try again.
```

Comment: This worked for me too. `Vagrant up` would produce this error if I tried to bring the box up after restarting the host.